# Symfony2 DI don't pass service as parameter

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

guys.

Help me please, I'm totally stuck.

/src/Application/Lexik/TranslationBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    lexik_translation.locale.loader.class: Application\Lexik\TranslationBundle\LocalesLoader\OrmLocalesLoader
    lexik_translation.locale.entity: Application\Lexik\TranslationBundle\Entity\Locale

services:
    lexik_translation.locale.repository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - %lexik_translation.locale.entity%

    lexik_translation.locale.loader:
        class: %lexik_translation.locale.loader.class%
        parameters:
            - @lexik_translation.locale.repository
```

src/Application/Ibrows/SonataTranslationBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ReplaceCrudControllerPass.php

```
namespace Application\Ibrows\SonataTranslationBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class ReplaceCrudControllerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('lexik_translation.locale.loader')) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('The "lexik_translation.locale.loader" configuration required.');
        }

        $definition = $container->getDefinition('ibrows_sonata_translation.admin.orm');
        $definition->setClass('Application\Ibrows\SonataTranslationBundle\Admin\ORMTranslationAdmin');
        $definition->replaceArgument(2, 'ApplicationIbrowsSonataTranslationBundle:TranslationCRUD');
        $definition->addMethodCall('setLocalesLoader', array(new Reference('lexik_translation.locale.loader')));
    }
}
```

And when I run any cli command or reload page, got next error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                                         
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Lexik\TranslationBundle\LocalesLoader\OrmLocalesLoader::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository, none given, called in /private/var/www/odesk/translate-admin/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2385 and defined
```

at appDevDebugProjectContainer.php have next (without injecting            @lexik_translation.locale.repository in constructor):

```
/**
 * Gets the 'lexik_translation.locale.loader' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return \Application\Lexik\TranslationBundle\LocalesLoader\OrmLocalesLoader A Application\Lexik\TranslationBundle\LocalesLoader\OrmLocalesLoader instance.
 */
protected function getLexikTranslation_Locale_LoaderService()
{
    return $this->services['lexik_translation.locale.loader'] = new \Application\Lexik\TranslationBundle\LocalesLoader\OrmLocalesLoader();
}
```

Why that matters? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have a typo. And realize that when post question.
Need pass `arguments:`, not `parameters:` at `services.yml`. Right one is:

```
services:
    lexik_translation.locale.repository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - %lexik_translation.locale.entity%

    lexik_translation.locale.loader:
        class: %lexik_translation.locale.loader.class%
        arguments: # < --- HERE WAS A TYPO
            - @lexik_translation.locale.repository
```